# What is the best way to deploy MEAN app and implement CI/CD pipelines on the app?

Tags: amazon-web-services, heroku, continuous-integration, mean-stack, continuous-deployment

So, I have a separate Angular frontend and Node JS backend. After doing a bunch of research, I've decided to publish my frontend to AWS S3, and backend to Heroku. Now, I want to understand how (or if) I can automate integration and deployment of both apps together or will I have to do it separately? So either I keep CI/CD of Angular side on S3 and Node side on Heroku or I can somehow manage both apps build/deploy automation at once.

Not sure, but here's a thought: If I deploy frontend on S3 and backend on Elastic beanstalk, does it make it easier to manage as AWS would somehow know to CI/CD both together.

Or ultimately, I'd have to keep them both separate and when I make changes to the Node side, the Angular side wouldn't even know to re-build and re-deploy.

Also, please don't suggest keeping them in one folder bc I need to keep them separate.

I'm even to hearing about more technologies to host my backend and frontend other than mentioned above like Netlify, Azure (ofc with explained advantages).

Answer (score 0):

Well there's no right or wrong way to implement this. Both approaches of keeping a same pipeline and separate one has it's own pros and cons. In my approach you should have 2 pipelines 1 for backend and 1 for frontend. Each of them should be independent of each other as well. So when 1 is triggered, other one doesn't care.

You can host Node app on AWS Lambda or AWS Fargate+ECS. Don't use AWS code pipeline as it's a very bad CI solution. https://buildkite.com/, CircleCI, Github Actions, etc are much better choice.